# Eclipse Proxy authorisation exception

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, windows-authentication

I am using Eclipse 3.5 along with JDK 1.6.0_23 (both on Laptop and desktop) within my organisation. The proxy server uses Windows domain authentication to pass through request.
While adding update sites within Eclipse available on Laptop, I could see that Eclipse is able to connect the site and doesn't throw authorisation exception. I have set the `Active Provider` in `Network Connections` as `Native`. I haven't configured my credentials in eclipse anywhere and it communicates with Proxy server smoothly.

I have similar settings on my desktop machine, but it throws Proxy Authorization exception. There is no clue in Error log. But it does displays a information indicating

> System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.

Similar messages do appear for `http.proxyPort` and https as well. I don't want to explicitly enter my credentials in Eclipse and hence looking for clues as why similar settings are behaving differently in these environments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse luna. I tried this link 
( http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/01/eclipse-not-able-to-connect-internet-market-place-configure-proxy-settings.html ) and it helped me resolve the problem!

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated, on SO.

Comment: Everything is explained in the article, what I would say would be an annoying repetition!

Comment: What if one day the link will change? your answer would be useless, then.

Comment: Well the explanation is based on snapshots, I couldn't explain it here. Until it is deleted, I am sure it will help some people!

Comment: It's better if you try to explain it in your words.

Comment: Hey @Zohra-tl thanks for replying, but as I mentioned in the question, I don't want to enter the credentials in the eclipse configuration, I don't prefer this option. I am aware of network configuration section, but eclipse should pickup system level settings.